# Как сделать метод который может выводить данные из суперкласса и подкласса

Tags: java, ооп

Есть суперкласс Animal и подкласс Cat. Также есть класс ветеринар с методом вывода информации о животном.
Как сделать этот метод  чтобы он мог выводить данные из суперкласса и подкласса?
Заранее спасибо!

```
 public class Animal {
        String location;
        String food;
        public void makeNoise(){
        System.out.println("rr");
    }
    public void eat(){
        System.out.println("hrr");
    }
    public void sleep(){
        System.out.println("zzz");
    }
    } 


    public class Cat extends Animal {
        String location="hz";
        String food="viskas";
        public void makeNoise(){
        System.out.println("may");
    }
    public void eat(){
        System.out.println("trr");
    }
    }

    public class Vet {
        ***public static void   treatAnimal(Animal animal){
    
            System.out.println(animal.food+" "+animal.location);***
    
       }
    }

public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal[] a=new Animal [1];
        a[0]=new Cat();
        for (int i=0; i<a.length;i++){
            Vet.treatAnimal( a[0]);
        }
        
    }}
```

Comment: Если ты хочешь вызвать метод родительского класса внутри перегруженного, то есть ключевое слово super. так же метод может содержать аннотацию @Override . если ты хочешь с обоими классами работать через один объект, то опиши интерфейс где будут методы и поля. и приведи оба класса к этому интерфейсу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Animal {
  public String getLocation() { return null; };
  public String getFood() { return null; };

  public void makeNoise() { System.out.println("rr"); }
  public void eat() { System.out.println("hrr"); }
  public void sleep() { System.out.println("zzz"); }
} 

public class Cat extends Animal {
  public String getLocation() { return "Greenland"; }
  public String getFood() { return "Viskas"; }
  public void makeNoise() { System.out.println("may"); }
  public void eat() { System.out.println("trr"); }
}

public class Vet {
  public static void treatAnimal(Animal animal) {
    System.out.println(animal.getFood() + " " + animal.getLocation());
  }
}
```

Comment: а будет-ли нулл поинтер выбрасываться если вызвать Vet.treatAnimal(new Animal())?

Comment: @Yakov Нет, выведется `"null null"`.

Comment: возврат null в методе это антипаттерн. так делать очень не рекомендуется. по уму надо делать из Animal  абстрактный класс либо интерфейс (не бывает просто животного, посему нечего давать возможность его инстанциировать) и фабричный метод для создания инстансов, дабы клиентский код (в виде ветеринара) имел ссылки только на Animal , а не на его имплементации/наследников (ну и класс с фабричным методом, если это не сам Animal ).